# ViewPager Title doesn't appear until I swipe it

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-viewpager

I am learning to use ViewPager and PagerTabStrip to implement navigation bar. I have implemented it, my problem is: every time I open the app fresh, the titles don't show, but after I swipe it once, the titles all appear again, and then everything is normal.
code shown below:

Customised Adapter

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private List<View> viewList;
    private List<String> titleList;

    public MyPagerAdapter(List<View> viewList, List<String> titleList){
        this.viewList = viewList;
        this.titleList = titleList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return viewList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
        return view == o;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        container.addView(viewList.get(position));
        return viewList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView(viewList.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return titleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

.xml File:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/tab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

This is the screenshot of "Just clicked the app icon":
[image]

And this is after I swiped to the second page:
[image]

I'm really frustrated. Thanks!!

Comment: you have your PagerTabStrip inside your viewpager, try placing it outside, by the way. you are passing the views as parameters in your constructor; that is not good for memory. Try using fragments, here is an example of how to do it http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html

Comment: Nope, did not solve the problem, also I believe I am supposed to put it inside the ViewPager.

Comment: Are you setting title on onPageSelected function?

Comment: I don't think I have a onPageSelected function...

Comment: Try extending your adapter as FragmentStatePagerAdapter instead of PagerAdapter, if you are using fragment.

Comment: But I'm not using any Fragments. I wouldn't be able to implement any of the methods.

Comment: you can always use whatever you need inside a Fragment

Comment: Sure, but what I need now, specifically for this question is to find out why this irregularity happens. As a matter of fact, I tried with a new project, the problem persists. But the same code works fine in the tutorial I'm watching. I want to know why that happens.

Comment: here is solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379050/how-can-we-work-around-the-blank-title-in-pagertitlestrip-and-pagertabstrip

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**It is an issue appeared in com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0**. You can refer here  https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183127

In that link google support team have mention that defect would be fixed in future releases. **So for now solution is build the project using com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1**

**Update : If feasible for you then you can go ahead with another solution provided by @nidheeshdas. I have tried on simple project; it work**
Modified solution of @nidheeshdas inside onResume() of Activity

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
    viewPager.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        }
    },100);
```

**New Update:** As mentioned in the above google issue tracker link and comments from  JP Ventura. I have tried with new version of library and issue seems to be fixed.

Comment: Updating dependency to "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1" and build tools version to "23.0.2" also works.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using ***android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip*** , use ***android.support.design.widget.TabLayout*** for displaying tabs for viewPager. It is included in Google Design Support Library.

See this link for more information 
http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

Just few lines:

```
viewPager=(ViewPager)v.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

ViewPagerAdapter adapter=new ViewPagerAdapter(this.getChildFragmentManager(),doctor);
adapter.setViewPagerFragmentListener(this);
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);  //Sync Tabs with viewPager
tabLayout.setTabsFromPagerAdapter(adapter);  //Setup tabs titles
```

And to change the titles use the following code in ViewPagerAdapter

```
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            return "Title 1";
        case 1:
            return "Title 2";
        case 2:
            return "Title 3";
    }
    return super.getPageTitle(position);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also recently started to have this problem, and after a little bit of testing I think I found a bug in Android's latest support package update.

The problem appears in to be in **com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0**.

Try changing the dependency back to **com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1** (second latest update) and see if that works.

Unfortunately, I have yet to find any solution to get it to work with the latest support package update.

Comment: I don't even get a response when I click on add dependency menu and library dependency, it just doesn't respond. I am going to uninstall Android Studio first and then reinstall it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Its seems to be working for me.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    pager.setCurrentItem(1);
    Task.delay(500).continueWith(new Continuation<Void, Object>() {
        @Override
        public Object then(Task<Void> task) throws Exception {
            pager.setCurrentItem(0);
            return null;
        }
    }, Task.UI_THREAD_EXECUTOR);
}
```

onResume set the pager to 1 and then back to 0. This makes the title appear the page loads the first time.